# Match hexadecimal values in a case statement

Tags: bash, hex

I'm trying to match exit codes of a process that is documented to return hexadecimal exit codes (e.g. `0x00` for success, `0x40 - 0x4F` on user error, `0x50 - 0x5F` on internal error, etc.).  I'd like to handle the exit code via a `case` statement, but the "obvious" solution doesn't match:

```
$ $val = 10

$ case $val in
>   0xA) echo match;;
>   *) echo no match;;
> esac
no match
```

Is there a readable way to match hexadecimal values in a `case` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the double-parentheses [arithmetic operator](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html) will display hex values as decimal, letting `case` match them.

```
$ echo $((0xA))
10

$ case $val in
>   $((0xA))) echo match;;
>   *) echo no match;;
> esac
match
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `printf` the value to a hex string:

```
case $(printf '%02x' $val) in
    0a) echo match;;
     *) echo no match;;
esac
```

This will allow you to match entire classes of error from your application:

```
case $(printf '%02x' $?) in
    00) echo success;;
    4?) echo user error;;
    5?) echo internal error;;
     *) echo unrecognised error;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

If the process return the string 0x0A, your case will fail then using 0xA. If it is really using numbers, you should use 10 in stead.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; clearly I can use `10`, but the exit codes are only meaningful in hex. Exit codes are not strings, they'll never be `0x0A`.

Comment: Now i understand your question.

Comment: Can you mark the top answer as the answer?